# How to seperate a Tensorflow dataset object in features and labels

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

My goal is it to feed a Keras model of an Autencoder only the (batches of) features from a tf.data.Dataset object.

Im loading the Dataset, format the Images and creating Batches like this:

```
#load dataset
(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs',
    split=[
    tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[:80]),
    tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[80:90]),
    tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[90:])],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True, 
    )

#normalize and resize images
IMG_SIZE = 160
def format_example(self, image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = (image/255.0) 
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return image, label
train = raw_train.map(format_example)
validation = raw_validation.map(format_example)
test = raw_test.map(format_example)

#create batches
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
BATCH_SIZE = 32
train_batches = train.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
validation_batches = validation.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_batches = test.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

And at this point i would like to seperate the batches in features and labels, something like this:

```
train_x_batches, train_y_batches = train_batches
```

But i get this error:

```
`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 train_x_batches, train_y_batches = train_batches

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`
```

Answer (score 2):

I get the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
train_x_batches = np.concatenate([x for x, y in train_batches], axis=0)
train_y_batches = np.concatenate([y for x, y in train_batches], axis=0)
```

And you can go back to your classes label using:

```
train_batches.class_names
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need only features for your autoencoder, you can slice them via `map`:

```
train_x_batches = train_batches.map(lambda features, labels: features)
```

Of course, you can do the same thing for your labels:

```
train_y_batches = train_batches.map(lambda features, labels: labels)
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I get the error `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`